# NullPointerException while fast updating TextField

Tags: java, events, javafx, observablelist

I'm working on an app, that searches some files in the directed folder and prints them in `TableView<myFile> foundFilesList`, that is stored in the Main class. `myFile` just extends `File` a bit. The searching is done using service in background thread, that puts found data to `ObservableList<myFile> filesOfUser`.
I want to display current amount of find files in `TextField foundFilesAmount` in the same view, where TableView with files is located -- `ResultsView`

To do that, I added a `ListChangeListener` for `foundFilesList` to `ResultsView` controller, that uses method `setText` to print current size of `filesOfUser`. It looks like:

```
Main.filesOfUser.addListener(new ListChangeListener<myFile>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends myFile> c) {
               while (c.next()){
                  if (c.wasAdded())
                        setCounter(c.getAddedSize());    
              }
        }
});
```

`void setCounter (int number)` contains only

```
  int currValue = Integer.valueOf(foundFilesAmount.getText());
  foundFilesAmount.setText(String.valueOf(currValue + number));
```

And now what the problem is. Textfield with current amount of find files is updated very fast, and from one moment it stops doing it. In the console I see lots of repeated `NullPointerException's` from JavaFX Application Thread. Its' contents:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:236)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.getRuns(Text.java:317)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.updatePGText(Text.java:1465)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_updatePeer(Text.java:1500)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_syncPeer(Node.java:503)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2290)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2419)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to set sort of delay before using `setText`, like updating value in `foundFilesAmount` only after 5'th, 10'th, 15'th update, etc. But if the search works longer, exceptions are still thrown.

Is there a correct method to show current amount of found files, that contains real amount and doesn't cause so much exceptions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is not doing the updates of the UI on a thread other than the application thread. This can otherwise lead to issues with rendering/layouting.

You could use a `Task` to do the updates to the updates however:

```
Task<ObservableList<myFile>> task = new Task<
Task<ObservableList<myFile>>() {
    @Override
    protected ObservableList<myFile> call() throws Exception {
        ObservableList<myFile> files = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        while (...) {
            ...
            files.add(...);
            updateMessage(Integer.toString(files.size()));
            ...
        }

        return files;
    }
};
task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> tableView.setItems(task.getValue()));
Thread t = new Thread(task);
textField.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
t.setDaemon(true);

t.start();
```

Comment: The search itself is done by `SimpleFileVisitor` in separate class. From task I can only start the searching by `Files.walkFileTree`. If I try to use method from controller, that updates my textField, in this separate class, I get `NullPointerException`, cause textField is not inizialised in other thread. That's why I used `ListChangeListener` there.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update your JavaFX controls here
        }
    });
```